# Switch git branch while keeping current branch in conflicted state

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I have a branch `master`. I created a new branch `feature`, made some changes to its files `fileA` and `fileB`. Meanwhile some changes were made to `master` also in the same files `fileA` and `fileB`. Now I merged `master` into `feature`. It shows conflicts in file `fileA` and `fileB`. Let's suppose, Now I decide to keep the feature branch in the same conflicted state and want to move to master.

`git checkout master` gives an error saying below:

```
fileA: needs merge

fileB: needs merge

error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

How may I switch to `master` while keeping `feature` as it is.

`EDIT`   Basically what happened is, I merged from master and some conflicts occurred which made my changes on feature useless. So I wanted to go back to master and cut out a new branch to work on the feature. At the same time, I dont want my earlier feature branch to be removed as it has some code that I may have to write again, hence I want to keep it to refer it as and when needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't leave it as is, but you can set your uncommitted changes aside and get back to the state you're currently in later.

- `git stash save` will set your uncommitted changes aside
- `git checkout master` to switch to master
- do whatever you want on master
- when you're done, `git checkout feature`
- `git stash show` will list all the changes you've stashed
- `git stash pop` will restore the last stashed changes

Comment: then is there a way to move to the commit, i was at before i merged ```feature``` with ```master```? @Brad

Comment: @GauravKumar I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish exactly. What is the point of merging the `master` changes into `feature` if you're then going to go back to where `feature` was before? (This is technically possible, but creates a 'detached HEAD' state which introduces other problems.)

Comment: Basically what happened is, I merged from master and some conflicts occurred which made my changes on feature useless. So I wanted to go back to master and cut out a new branch to work on the feature. At the same time, I dont want my earlier feature branch to be removed as it has some code that I may have to write again, hence I want to keep it to refer it as and when needed. @Brad

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You cannot switch away from a branch and have it retain an unmerged or conflicted state. That state applies only to your working directory, not to a branch specifically.

There are changes in your working directory that are not tracked by Git. You need to resolve those changes and commit them, otherwise they would be lost when you switch branches.